# How to change my name that appears in email depending on language?

Tags: gmail

I write emails in Russian and English and I'd like to send my Russian emails with Russian name and emails in English with my name's translation to English. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no "easy" way to set that up.  However, with a little configuration, there is a fairly user-friendly solution.

What you could do is set up a second Gmail account (or Yahoo!, or Hotmail, or any other webmail account) and specify your name for that account as your Russian name.  Then, add that account to your main Gmail account as an account that you own (instructions for doing that can be found [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)).

Once you've set up the second account and added it to your main Gmail account, you can now switch between the two when you send emails.  When you send an email in English, you won't have to do anything, and when you send one in Russian, just click the **From** button in the compose email window and select your second account. (Instructions for doing that can also be found in the link above.)

It's not ideal, but it does allow you to switch "from" addresses with just a click or two, after the initial setup.